# How can i use a variable and a method from form1 to a new class file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have in form1 top:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> codeToFullNameMap;
private string mainPath = "Countries";
```

Then in form1 constructor

```
ManageDirectories();
```

Then the ManageDirectories

```
private void ManageDirectories()
        {
            string savedImagesPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            mainPath = Path.Combine(savedImagesPath, mainPath);
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CountriesNames.txt");
            foreach (string path in lines)
            {
                string countryPath = Path.Combine(mainPath, path);
                if (!Directory.Exists(countryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
                }
                countries.Add(path);
            }

            string[] countriesCodes = File.ReadAllLines("CountriesCodes.txt");
            foreach (string code in countriesCodes)
            {
                codes.Add(code);
            }

            codeToFullNameMap = codes
                .Select((code, index) => index)
                .ToDictionary(
                              keySelector: index => codes[index],
                              elementSelector: index => countries[index]);
        }
```

Now in the class file

```
var startIndex = file.Name.IndexOf("region=") + "region=".Length;
var length = file.Name.IndexOf("&", startIndex) - startIndex;
var code = file.Name.Substring(startIndex, length);
var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[code];

string countryPath = Path.Combine(mainPath, countryName);
```

But in the class file i created both codeToFullNameMap and mainPath are not exist.

How can i use them after the code was doing anything in ManageDirectories in form1 in the new class without making a new instance of form1 ? Or what is the best way to be able to use them in the class ? I could also make them public static.

Comment: What is the "class file" and how is it invoked from the form?  Whatever method you're calling you could simply add those values as parameters to that method.

Comment: what class is your "file" instance?

Comment: I am guessing that the class file is a separate file?